# Неправильное отображение в Genymotion(dpi)

Tags: android, android-studio, экран, genymotion

Разрешение 720х1280.
Выбираю 160dpi - разрешение становится большим.
Выбираю 320dpi - разрешение уменьшается.
Но если я не ошибаюсь и ничего не путаю, то должно быть все наоборот о_О

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Всё правильно. DPI значит "точек на дюйм", в данном случае имеется в виду экранный дюйм. В итоге 720х1080 в разрешении 160 dpi будут занимать область 4.5x6.75 дюймов, а в разрешении 320 - 2.25x3.375 дюймов. Увеличиваться разрешение от увеличения точек на дюйм может при обратном процессе, когда изображение с фиксированным размером в **дюймах** переводится в растр, например, при сканировании.